# Kafka Connect Distributed is not working

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to run kafka connect in distributed mode to read from topic and write to HDFS.
The process is starting successfully with the required properties files given, but I am not able to commit the events to HDFS.

Please see the full logs below.

Note: Broker details have been masked and all other details are mentioned in the logs.

```
[2018-06-26 11:49:48,474] INFO ConsumerConfig values:
        auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
        auto.offset.reset = earliest
        bootstrap.servers = [****:****, ****:****]
        check.crcs = true
        client.id = consumer-3
        connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
        enable.auto.commit = false
        exclude.internal.topics = true
        fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
        fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
        fetch.min.bytes = 1
        group.id = connect-cluster
        heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
        interceptor.classes = null
        key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
        max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
        max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
        max.poll.records = 500
        metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
        receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
        reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
        request.timeout.ms = 305000
        retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
        security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
        send.buffer.bytes = 131072
        session.timeout.ms = 10000
        ssl.cipher.suites = null
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
        ssl.key.password = null
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        ssl.protocol = TLS
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS
        value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig:180)
[2018-06-26 11:49:48,476] WARN The configuration 'config.storage.topic' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig:188)
[2018-06-26 11:49:48,476] WARN The configuration 'status.storage.topic' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig:188)
[2018-06-26 11:49:48,476] WARN The configuration 'internal.key.converter.schemas.enable' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig:188)
[2018-06-26 11:49:48,476] WARN The configuration 'rest.port' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig:188)
[2018-06-26 11:49:48,476] WARN The configuration 'value.converter.schema.registry.url' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig:188)
[2018-06-26 11:49:48,476] WARN The configuration 'internal.key.converter' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig:188)
[2018-06-26 11:49:48,476] WARN The configuration 'internal.value.converter.schemas.enable' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig:188)
[2018-06-26 11:49:48,476] WARN The configuration 'internal.value.converter' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig:188)
[2018-06-26 11:49:48,476] WARN The configuration 'offset.storage.topic' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig:188)
[2018-06-26 11:49:48,476] WARN The configuration 'value.converter' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig:188)
[2018-06-26 11:49:48,476] WARN The configuration 'key.converter' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig:188)
[2018-06-26 11:49:48,477] WARN The configuration 'key.converter.schema.registry.url' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig:188)
[2018-06-26 11:49:48,477] INFO Kafka version : 0.10.1.0-IBM-8 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:83)
[2018-06-26 11:49:48,477] INFO Kafka commitId : unknown (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:84)
[2018-06-26 11:49:48,682] INFO Discovered coordinator ****:**** (id: 2147483644 rack: null) for group connect-cluster. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:555)
[2018-06-26 11:49:48,686] INFO Finished reading KafkaBasedLog for topic connect-test-configs (org.apache.kafka.connect.util.KafkaBasedLog:148)
[2018-06-26 11:49:48,686] INFO Started KafkaBasedLog for topic connect-test-configs (org.apache.kafka.connect.util.KafkaBasedLog:150)
[2018-06-26 11:49:48,686] INFO Started KafkaConfigBackingStore (org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.KafkaConfigBackingStore:261)
[2018-06-26 11:49:48,687] INFO Herder started (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:171)
[2018-06-26 11:49:48,689] INFO Discovered coordinator ****:**** (id: 2147483644 rack: null) for group connect-cluster. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:555)
[2018-06-26 11:49:48,691] INFO (Re-)joining group connect-cluster (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:381)
[2018-06-26 11:49:48,702] INFO Successfully joined group connect-cluster with generation 3 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:349)
[2018-06-26 11:49:48,702] INFO Joined group and got assignment: Assignment{error=0, leader='connect-1-67ad9053-4b20-41dd-9a6a-ec8e4f4d622e', leaderUrl='http://****:****/', offset=-1, connectorIds=[], taskIds=[]} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1009)
[2018-06-26 11:49:48,702] INFO Starting connectors and tasks using config offset -1 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:745)
[2018-06-26 11:49:48,702] INFO Finished starting connectors and tasks (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:752)
[2018-06-26 11:49:55,748] INFO Reflections took 7022 ms to scan 225 urls, producing 15521 keys and 98977 values  (org.reflections.Reflections:229)
```

Comment: Looks like it's starting to me... What's the problem? Where's the error? Please show your JSON connector property file that you've posted to connect (if you have)

Comment: Just want to know where should we give the properties of the topics,hdfs url,task in a distributed mode? Should we pass it to a separate hdfs.properties file?

Answer (score 1):

> but I am not able to commit the events to HDFS

When you start distributed mode, it doesn't take any individual connector properties, you load those later

> Just want to know where should we give the properties of the topics,hdfs url,task in a distributed mode?

You [POST JSON into it](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect_rest).

Make a `connect-hdfs.json` file, for example

```
{
   "name": "quickstart-hdfs-sink"
   "config": {
      "store.url": "hdfs:///apps/kafka-connect",
      "hadoop.conf.dir": "/etc/hadoop/conf",
      "topics" :  ... 
   }
}
```

Send it to Connect

```
curl -XPOST -d@connect-hdfs.json http://connect-server:8083/connectors
```